# How can I prove this bijection relationship?

Tags: functions

Suppose that $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is any function and define a new function $g : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by the formula $g(x) = 2f(x+1)$. Show that $f$ is a bijection $\iff$ $g$ is a bijection.

I am not sure at all on how to go about starting this proof. I know that I should assume that $f$ is a bijection and then assume that $g$ is a bijection to prove both sides of the $\iff$ statement but I am not sure how to begin. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If we have that $f$ is a bijection, then it is pretty easy to get that $g$ is a bijection. Remember that a bijection is a function that is one-to-one and onto. Simply go back to the definitions.

Now assume $g$ is a bijection, but suppose $f$ is not a bijection. Then $f$ fails to be either one-to-one or onto. Consider both cases. You get a contradiction in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (more abstract) :

1. define $t_1 : x \rightarrow x+1$ and $h : x \rightarrow 2x $ ,
2. prove that $t_1$ and $h$ are bijections
3. write $g = h \circ f \circ t_1$
4. use the theorem that bijections from a set to himself form a group with the composition law (called *symmetric group*)